# Filter on Maybe, elm

Tags: elm

I have a `List (Maybe a)` and i want to filter out the instances of `Nothing`. I have presumably managed to do it, but am not happy with the amount of code I needed:

```
removeNothingFromList : List (Maybe a) -> List a 
removeNothingFromList list =
    List.foldr
        (\cur list ->
            case cur of
                Just val ->
                    val :: list

                Nothing ->
                    list
        )
        []
        list
```

in js the analog is accomplished simply by `const removeNothingFromList = (list) => list.filter(item => item)` and i would hope that its just my inexperience that is preventing me from seeing a comperably terse solution.

Furthermore, is there generally a way to check for type (cast to bool), or filter on type in general?

Comment: Simon H has the correct answer.

Your javascript code is broken. I just used it to filter nothings from my list of temperature readings = `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0]` and it filtered out all of my good data. 0 isn't nothing. It's a perfectly valid temperature. Whoops! 

What you are bothered by is that correct Elm code is longer than incorrect, unsafe JS. Judging by the views count, 32 people didn't notice that 1 line of Javascript was incorrect!

I hope you see the value of Elm and the few extra characters it might require.

Comment: @z5h I was entirely aware of that limitation to my analog, which is why i called it an analog and not an equivalent. Furthermore, I am not on stackoverflow to be lecture on the benefits of strong typing.

Comment: my comment is for the sake of all readers. There is a disturbing trend I see where language and framework developers strongly advertise how you can get more done with less code, as if the number of keys one has to type is the difficult part of writing code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your aim can be achieved through composition of two elements of the core packages:

```
removeNothingFromList : List (Maybe a) -> List a 
removeNothingFromList list =
    List.filterMap identity list
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`elm-community/maybe-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/4.0.0/Maybe-Extra) package exposes a function called [`Maybe.Extra.values`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/maybe-extra/4.0.0/Maybe-Extra#values) which is what you're looking for.

You can do a search on all public packages using the [Elm Fancy Search](http://klaftertief.github.io/elm-search/?q=List%20(Maybe%20a)%20->%20List%20a) tool. Searching on the type signature of `List (Maybe a) -> List a` will bring up the package I mentioned.